# Scraping website using Excel VBA and XML

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape Newegg website to get price of products. When I run this piece of code it does the job.

```
Sub test()

Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
Set objIE = New InternetExplorer

objIE.Visible = True
objIE.Navigate "https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?item=1TS-000E-083F2"

Do While objIE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Loop

    Debug.Print objIE.Document.getElementsByClassName("price-current")(0).Children(1).innerText

End Sub
```

However, when I try to use XML for faster executing I am having a **run time error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set**

Below is the piece of code I am trying to implement.

```
Sub testxml()

Dim XMLPage As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument



XMLPage.Open "GET", "https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?item=1TS-000E-083F2", False
XMLPage.send

HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLPage.responseText


Debug.Print HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("price-current")(0).Children(1).innerText
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to get `innerText` property for 2nd `Child` of collection element obtained through this code:

```
HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("price-current")(0)
```

This error happens, because "Object" from error prompt which is `HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("price-current")(0)` does not exist on this page.

You can check it with:

```
Debug.Print HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("price-current").Length
```

It will be 0, meaning no element with this class exists. If it exists for IE automation, it means that this element is part of HTML generated through JavaScript and XMLHTTP request will not have it in its response.

Comment: Thank you for explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

does this help?

```
Dim XMLPage As Object
Dim HTMLDoc As Object


Set XMLPage = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Set HTMLDoc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
```

There are some articles on stack about when to use new etc. so I am not gonna cover it.